# In C, write() returns bad file descriptor error

Tags: c, system-calls, file-descriptor

I'm writing a program that takes a file as a command line argument and then counts the amount of words/tokens in the file. It is supposed to open the file as read-only and if it doesn't exist, it creates it. I have tried all sorts of solutions but I continue to get the "Bad file descriptor" error once I reach the write() call. I'm new to using these system calls so I'm not sure where I am making a mistake.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* get_token(int fd);

int main(int argv, char* argc[]){
    int fd = open(argc[1], O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);
    if(fd == -1){
        perror("Open error");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        int count = 0;
    char* next_token = get_token(fd);
    int write_return = 1;
    while(next_token != NULL){
        int char_count = 0;
        while(next_token[count] != '\n'){
            write_return = write(fd, &next_token[char_count], 1);
            if(write_return == -1){
                perror("Writing failure");
                return(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            char_count++;
        }
        if(next_token[count] == '\n'){
            write_return = write(fd, &next_token[char_count], 1);
            if(write_return == -1){
                perror("Writing failure");
                return(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    close(fd);
    printf("%d\n", count);

}
```

The get_tokens function goes through each word, using read() to add each character to the buffer, until it reaches whitespace. Then it returns the buffer.

```
char* get_token(int fd){
    int size = 50;
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(size);
    int count = 0;
    int read_return = read(fd, &buffer[count], 1);
    if(read_return == -1){
        perror("Reading error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(buffer[count] != ' ' && buffer[count] != '\t' && buffer[count] != '\n'){
        count++;
        read_return = read(fd, &buffer[count], 1);
        if(read_return == -1){
            perror("Reading error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(count == size-2){
            size += 10;
            buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, size);
        }
    }
    buffer[count] = '\n';
    return buffer;
}
```

I will appreciate any and all help I can get. Thank you.

Comment: You're opening a file for read only and wondering why you can't write to it?

Comment: `O_RDONLY | O_CREAT` ?? you expect to *write* on that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you open a file in read-only mode, then you cannot write to it.  It's a bad file descriptor.  If you want to write to the file, open it O_RDWR.

Comment: I was trying to write to the command line, but didn't realize that I was not supposed to use my file descriptor here. So I replaced fd in write() with 0 and now all is well.